# Any way to shuffle the output of $this->getLoadedProductCollection()

Tags: collection, product-list, product-collection, random

Is there any way to shuffle this foreach?

I tried `shuffle($_productCollection)` and `array_rand($_productCollection)` but nothing worked :(

```
<?php  $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); 
if ($_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()): ?>
<?php $tpl=Mage::helper('config'); ?>
        <div class="slides row1">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection is an iterator and not an array, array functions do not work with iterators. But you can convert it.

```
$productArray = iterator_to_array($productCollection);
shuffle($productArray);
```

Then use `$productArray` in the foreach loop.